# ftp uploaded files are not in the library of Media module

Tags: media, files

I installed media module in Drupal 7 to browse the uploaded files on the server. I created a new field called `media3` and this is its configuration.

[image]

This is the next page :

[image]

The problem is when I'm trying to add new content to this content type and select them in the library tab from media module, only the image files that are already uploaded through `http` protocol are displayed.

If I check the `Allowed URI schemes` checkbox, nothing will be displayed in the library tab.
 how do I can browse the ftp uploaded files? where they should be to be visible to media module?

Comment: So what are owner and permission settings on them, versus ones you see available?

Comment: @Mołot they are 0644

Comment: Both ones visible and invisible to libraries mentioned? And what about owner?

Comment: Only `http` uploaded files are visible, their permission is 0644 as well. Where should I upload the files? is there any specific folder?

Comment: But what is the owner? I could bet you a dollar that http uploaded files are owned by someone like `www-data` and ftp uploaded ones  are owned by someone like `drupalist`.

Comment: I uploaded the files (administrator) and I can't see them

Comment: I mean Unix usernames attached to these files, not Drupal user... I would be surprised if 1) there would be user named `administrator` on your server and 2) your server's configuration would allow administrator owned files to be read by webserver on client's demand.

Comment: These is no `administrator` username. where is the Unix username attached to it?!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sX6Zv.png (Note - what you see there is mostly a mockup, not a real directory with "everything allowed" settings. In other words - don't copy it, it's only for show!)

Comment: @Mołot The file owner in my computer is A4-PC. What can I do with this? I need to create a user in the website and set the username to `A4-PC` ?

Comment: But I mean a file owner on the server. That's what matters. Screenshot is from WinSCP.

Comment: I found the owner on the server, what else do I need to do ?

Comment: Compare owner of the files that are OK with the owner of the ones that you uploaded via ftp. If there is no difference, we just excluded most common issue.

Comment: I find the file owner on the server using FileZilla, but at this time Filezilla doesn't connect to the server :( . I will let you on it as soon as it connects

Comment: @Mołot they all have the same owner/group

Answer (score 1):

The media module, like pretty much all of the file related modules on Drupal, relies on the managed files system which involves adding data to the db for files that are uploaded, simply using ftp to place them in the appropriate directory bypasses the "drupal way" and doesn't create these database rows, so the media module doesn't know about the files. I have used this method with other modules but not media:

::I do not claim that this is the best way to handle it, but it has worked for my use cases::

The following are the contents of a custom module I through together and assume a few things, first that your node type is "picture", second that you are just using the default "file" field that comes with drupal, and lastly that only files you are aware of exist in the directory "/sites/default/files/importer":

```
function MYMODULE_menu(){
    $info['db_pics']=array(
        'title' => 'NCD Callbacks',
        'page callback' => 'db_pics_callback',
        'access callback' => 'pics_is_admin',
    );
    return $info;
}
function pics_is_admin(){
    global $user;
    return ($user->uid==1);
}
function db_pics_callback(){
    $url='./sites/default/files/importer';
    $files=traverse($url);
    foreach($files as $source){
        $node=new stdClass();
        $node->type='picture';
        $node->uid=1;
        $node->status=1;

        //This part is optional and just allowed me to create a node using metadata from the image file
        //Get file info
        $fn=exif_read_data($source);
        if(!isset($fn['DateTime'])){
            $fn['DateTime']=$last_dt;
        }else{
            $last_dt=$fn['DateTime'];
        }

        $node->title=$fn['FileName'];
        $names[]=$node->title;
        $node->created=strtotime($fn['DateTime']);

        //Fetch the actual data from the image file
        $image = file_get_contents($source);

        // Returns the new file object after saving the image to the appropriate Drupal File schema
        $file = file_save_data($image, 'public://'.$fn['FileName'], FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
        $node->field_image['und'][0]=(array) $file;
        node_save($node);
    }
    return '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>',$names).'</li></ul>';
}

//quick and dirty utility function assumes only files you want are in the specified directories
function traverse($url){
    $entries=array();
    $dir=scandir($url);
    foreach($dir as $entry){
        if(in_array($entry,array('.','..'))) continue;
        elseif(is_dir($url.'/'.$entry)){
            $entries=$entries+traverse($url.'/'.$entry);
        }else{
            $entries[]=$url.'/'.$entry;
        }
    }
    return $entries;
}
```

This is a little different than what you asked for, but I see people asking for this functionality frequently so I wanted to give a complete answer about importing files as nodes, for your specific use case the callback function can be significantly shortened to:

```
function db_pics_callback(){
    $url='./sites/default/files/importer';
    $files=traverse($url);
    $saved_files=db_query('SELECT filename FROM file_managed')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    foreach($files as $source){
        $image = file_get_contents($source);
        $fn=substr($source,strrpos($source,'/')+1);
        if(!in_array($fn,$saved_files)){
            file_save_data($image, 'public://'.$fn, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
        }
    }
    return 'Finished';
}
```

That should add all of your files to the managed files database table and allow you to view them in the "Library" tab. Good luck!